# Absolutely lost on how to use js async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, snapshot

I am using Javascript for a project and this the first time I've used it so I am a bit lost on how to use ascyn function.

I have a firebase/firestore database and I am trying to get a document id from it. I believe below is a good starting point for my code.

```
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
    console.log('saving ingredent:', arrayCopy[i].ingredent)
    console.log('ingredent id:', getIId(arrayCopy, i))
}
```

This snippet of code should log the names of the document based on a given array value.
Moving forward the getIId is as follows

```
export async function getIId(arrayCopy, i){
    const cIngredent = arrayCopy[i].ingredent
    var iID

    const ingredientRef = collection(fsdb, 'ingredientInfo')

    const q = query(ingredientRef, where("ingredientName", "==", cIngredent))

    onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
        const ingredientSnap = snapshot.docs
        if(ingredientSnap.length != 0){
            let ingredents = []
            console.log('idCheck onSnapshot 2',ingredientSnap[0].id)
            iID = ingredientSnap[0].id
            ingredents.push(iID)
            console.log('array: ', ingredents)
            return ingredents
        }else{
            console.log('theres no value')
            console.log('idCheck onSnapshot else 2',iID)
            return iID
        }
    })

    console.log('outside iiD: ', iID)
}
```

what ends up happening is that

```
ingredent id: underfined
```

Comes before the values of the ingredients

```
idCheck onSnapshot ###############
idCheck onSnapshot 2 ###############
array [###############]
```

Where ############### is the correct document id. I am not sure how to get the right value from onSnapshot and have it return to as the value from getIId. Once again the value before the return inside onSnapShot is correct.

Comment: Asynchronous functions happen outside of the normal event queue. This means that these functions do not run as soon as they are called. Instead, they return a Promise, which is a signal that a function hasn't been executed yet. The return value can only be used once the promise has resolved.  You could be running into a problem where you are trying to log a value before it has been resolved.

Comment: getIID needs to return a Promise that calls resolve() once it's ready (instead of returning). Then you need to `await` getIID in your console.log line. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 1):

You need to return something from inside if your `getIId` function, there is no magic, if you want to use onSnapshot - then you need to wrap it in a Promise object and return this object with handling reject and resolve (and dont forget to [unsubscribe](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots) from onSnapshot after that) but if you need to get a result only once - use `getDocs`.

Examples: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

So your code will look like

```
export async function getIId(arrayCopy, i) {
  const cIngredent = arrayCopy[i].ingredent;
  const ingredientRef = collection(fsdb, "ingredientInfo");

  const q = query(ingredientRef, where("ingredientName", "==", cIngredent));
  const getDocsResult = await getDocs(q);
  const result = getDocsResult.docs.map((x) => x.id);

  if (result.length === 0) {
    console.log("No items found");
    return undefined;
  } else {
    console.log("array: ", result);
    return result[0]; // we need only 1 item, right?
  }
}
```

also, the function that will use `getIId` will need to `await` for the result of this function. Or to use getIId(...).then(res => console.log(res));

```
export async function something(arrayCopy) {
  const len = arrayCopy.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    console.log("saving ingredent:", arrayCopy[i].ingredent);
    console.log("ingredent id:", await getIId(arrayCopy, i));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that onSnapshot and associated callbacks are correct, you just need to add a return to the async function.

```
return iID
```

Then the for loop should loop like this in order to make sure everything prints in the right order

```
for(let i = 0; i < len; i++){
    getIId(arrayCopy, i).then((id)=>{
         console.log('saving ingredent:', arrayCopy[i].ingredent)
         console.log('ingredent id:', id)
    }
    )
}
```

Comment: onSnapshot does not return a promise.

Comment: The author doesn't specify any declaration. so it is unknown. I will clarify this in the answer

Comment: it is just in his question and tags, firebase/firestore

Comment: And still, onSnapshot is asynchronous but it does not return a promise, returning iID will not help, sadly

Comment: Since onSnapshot changes the value of the iID value, wouldn't you need to await the return of the function?

Comment: Asynchronous (not async) function is not always awaitable, there was "something" before promises and async/await for asynchronous operations, a `callbacks`, googled nice with `callback hell`. So onSnapshot is one of those functions, it is not awaitable, it does not return a promise, it is a "listener" that you set for something and it executes the callback you passed to it. Sure you do need to await but you need to add awaitable logic manually, like wrap this function with a new Promise((resolve, reject => ....)